# Difference between subject.sign_in_count and object.sign_in_count

Tags: rspec, devise

I had override the sessions controller class of Devise. I am trying to write a test using rspec. In this, want to verify if a user with wrong credentials pass the test. Googling I found that I should to use expect(subject.current_admin_user.sign_in_count).to eq(0) to verify that. But my test fail because subject.current_admin_user.sign_in_count = 1. but when I use user_admin.sign_in_count my test pass. Why this difference could you help me please?

```
RSpec.describe ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController, type: :controller do

  let(:user_admin) { create(:admin_user_with_r) }

  describe "POST #create_session" do
  it "verify a valid user" do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin_user]
  post :create, {
    :admin_user => {
      username: user_admin.username,
      email: user_admin.email,
      password: user_admin.password
    }
  }
  expect(subject.current_admin_user.sign_in_count).to eq(0)
  binding.pry
 end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

This might help: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/subject/implicit-subject

In short, you have an implicit `subject` defined when running this test which is not the same as the `user_admin` that you create in your test.